# fill in field in cucumber not able to access the input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have the below code as a .erb file:

```
<div class="gridster">
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Repository</legend>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="gitrepoURL">GitHub URL</label>
      <input type="url" name="GithubRepo" id="gitrepoURL" placeholder="http://github.com/<organization>/<repo>" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <input type="button" name="Add" id="add" value="Add Repository" class="add" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

In one of the cucumber unit test cases i wrote:

```
When /^I update the input field with a github url $/ do
  visit '/github/index' 
  fill_in "field[GithubRepo]", :with => "http://github.com/name1/name2"
end
```

i understood that im using the incorrect dom to access the GithubRepo. I tried looking in firebug to access the GithubRepo field properly to fill the url, but could not and when ran the test case using cucumber, it says

```
When(/^I update the input field with a github url$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

and stops executing the test cases that are below this one. Let me know if my understanding is wrong. If i'm right, let me know how to access the dom element so that i can use it to access other elements and write other test cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two problems in your Cucumber step:

1. There is an extra space in the regex, which is why Cucumber does not find the step.
2. The value being passed to `fill_in` is incorrect - it should be the name, id or label text.

Try the following:

```
When /^I update the input field with a github url$/ do
  visit '/github/index' 
  fill_in "GithubRepo", :with => "http://github.com/name1/name2"
end
```

Noting that the following changes were made:

1. The space was removed at the end of the regex (ie between url and $).
2. `fill_in` was changed to use the field's name.

Comment: You are right, i figured that out after reading the error carefully. Thank you.